# v-for custom component checkbox not working

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I am using v-for with a custom component

```
Vue.component('lineitem', {
  template: '#lineitem-template',
  props: {
    item: {
      required: false,
      default: null
    },
  },
  computed: {
    local_line_item() {
      console.log("Re computing line item")
      return _.clone(this.item)
    },
  },
  methods: {
    set_taxable(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      if (this.local_line_item.taxable == false) {
        this.local_line_item.taxable = true;
      } else {
        this.local_line_item.taxable = false;
      }
      console.log("Changing taxable to ", this.local_line_item);
    },
  }
});
```

with this template:

```
<template id="lineitem-template">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="local_line_item.cost">
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class="option" @click="set_taxable">
        <input type="checkbox" v-model="local_line_item.taxable" v-bind:true-value="true" v-bind:false-value="false">
        <label for="check1"></label>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</template>
```

see this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shaunc869/1Ly7mL6n/7/

When I click the checkbox I am changing the value of the internal variable, but the checkbox doesn't change, what am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`e.preventDefault()` inside `set_taxable` is the cause of problem. Removing that part works just fine. You can see the updated fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/1Ly7mL6n/9/

Also, I don't understand your rationale behind using the click binding to trigger `set_taxable`. Since you have already used `v-model` binding to toggle `local_line_item.taxable` in accordance with the checked state of the checkbox, you do not need a click handler for it. So unless you plan to do some more operations in the click handler, you could remove that as well.

Comment: Sorry I should have bee more specific on this, basically I want to be able to able to check the box using some kind of other trigger, programmatically, I updated my fiddle to show this point a little clearer. Can you look at the updated fiddle and let me know what you think? Thanks!

Comment: Hey, you didn't provide the link to your updated fiddle. Also, if you wish to toggle the checkbox's state programmatically, you could do that via `local_line_item.taxable` as it is bound to the checkbox via `v-model`. Can you elaborate on *what* you are trying to achieve, if possible? Do read, [What is X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I apologize, I forgot to include the updated version number:

https://jsfiddle.net/shaunc869/1Ly7mL6n/12

I did try to do that, but when I change the value of local_line_item.taxable it didn't seem to switch.

Comment: I can't spot the problem in that fiddle, but in general toggling the property bound to `v-model` should be able to toggle the checkbox: https://jsfiddle.net/1Ly7mL6n/16/